# parskip clashes with thmbox of thmtools

Tags: thmtools, parskip, thmbox

I have a problem using the **parskip** and **thmtools** packages. I want to use the boxes provided by thmtools to frame my theorems lemmas etc. The one I'm interested in is the **thmbox=M** box but as soon as the parskip package is loaded everything goes wrong.
The reason I don't want to give up on **parskip** is that I don't like automatic indentation and it's very practical to space out paragraphs.

Let me illustrate this with codes and images.

Without parskip loaded:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[without parskip]
blabla bla bla,
\[\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.\]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Which gives the following result,

[image]

With parskip loaded:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[with parskip]
blabla bla bla,
\[\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.\]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

resulting in a mess,

[image]

Does any one has a solution to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

`thmbox` initializes the value of option `leftmargin` to `\parindent`. Thus if `thmbox` is loaded *after* `parskip`, `leftmargin` is set to 0pt and the problem reproduces:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{thmbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{thmbox}[M]{The title}
  Some text, some more text, asufficient amount to get afull box with several lines.
\end{thmbox}

% with `article` class option 12pt, \parindent defaults to 1.5em
\begin{thmbox}[M,leftmargin=1.5em]{The title}
  Some text, some more text, asufficient amount to get afull box with several lines.
\end{thmbox}
\end{document}
```

[image: thmbox example]

For direct use of `thmbox`, loading it before `parskip` works.

The situation is a little bit messer for `thmtools`: it loads `thmbox` only when `\declaretheorem` option `thmbox={<thmbox options>}` is used for the first time.  It's still feasible to load `parskip` after all such `\declaretheorem` usages, but here I suggest to load `parskip` in a late hook used after the whole preamble and just before `begindocument`: `begindocument/before` (It's equivalent to `\AtEndPreamble` from `etoolbox` package.)

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}

\declaretheorem[thmbox={M,leftmargin=1.5em}]{theorem}

\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{%
  \usepackage{parskip}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[with parskip]
  blabla bla bla,
  \[\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.\]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image: thmtools example, using hook "begindocument/before"]

One can also backup the value of `\parindent` before loading `parskip`, and then pass that value to `thmbox` option `leftmargin`, like

```tex
\newlength{\origparindent}
\setlength{\origparindent}{\parindent}
\usepackage{parskip}
...
\declaretheorem{thmbox={M,leftmargin=\origparindent}}{theorem}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand a lot better now, and I think I'll be able to do what I have in mind with all your solutions!